# Visual Studio 2022 always resetting IIS App Pool on build

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2022

I have a Visual Studio 2022 solution with multiple .NET Core Web API projects, all hosted locally on IIS via launchSettings.json.

It seems to reset the IIS App pool each time you build, and if there are multiple projects, it does them one by one, in sequence. This is not a problem if there are code changes that needs to be applied, but it does it even when there is nothing new to build.

[IIS App Pool stopped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJdf9.png)

[No builds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehDX7.png)

The behavior I am looking for is for it to only reset the app pool if any new code actually is changed, basically the same behavior as the code build skipping when it detects no changes.

I have looked over the launchSettings specification, and Visual Studio/Solution/Project configuration, but have not found any way to get this behavior.

Comment: Many settings of VS/IIS integration are not exposed to end users to change. You might report to Microsoft and see what's the explanation, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

Comment: @LexLi Thank you. I have created a feature request there. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS2022---Only-restart-IIS-App-Pool-on-co/10565157

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.